# PHP/JSON Array - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() using Riot Games API

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am returning to an old project that I created using Riot Games API but had to update the wrapper I was using (https://github.com/kevinohashi/php-riot-api) - my test enviornment is http://sutsurikeru.com/fallingmoon/ - all errors are outputted here.

Everything worked a treat befre updating the wrapper, but this was some time ago and Riot's API has changed since as well.

Firstly I get the following:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sites
/sutsurikeru.com/public_html/fallingmoon/index.php on line 50
```

which relates to following:

```
//sorts by number of league points
foreach($array as $key => $league){
    usort($array[$key]['entries'], function($a,$b){
        return $a['leaguePoints'] - $b['leaguePoints'];
    });
}
```

If there is something I have overlooked, any advice is greatly appreciated!

Full pastebin of my script: http://pastebin.com/9JzNSvcU

Comment: if you do a var_dump($array); before the loop, what do you have?

Comment: Most like you pass an empty variable to foreach

Comment: it means your $array  is empty .please submit your full code

Comment: Full code is in the pastebin and sameple of the vardump - string(33477) "{"24381045":[{"name":"Vladimir's Army","tier":"GOLD","queue":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","entries":[{"playerOrTeamId":"43642827","playerOrTeamName":"esquimo14","division":"V","leaguePoints":0,"wins":60,"losses":46,"... - you can see the vardump at http://sutsurikeru.com/fallingmoon

Comment: `$array = json_encode($r, true);` - You can't use a JSON string in a foreach loop. You probably meant `json_decode`.

Comment: `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` and the var dump of the $array returns `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding `['0']` after `$array[$key]`

```
foreach($array as $key => $league){
    usort($array[$key]['0']['entries'], function($a,$b){
        return $b['leaguePoints'] - $a['leaguePoints'];
    });
```

}